# Dynamic Arrray Size in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, ram, xilinx, vivado

I want to use dynamic range of array , so using "N" for converting an incoming vector signal to integer.  Using the specifc incoming port "Size" gives me an error, while fixed vector produces perfect output.

```
architecture EXAMPLE of Computation is

signal size :std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

process (ACLK, SLAVE_ARESETN) is

variable N: integer:=conv_integer  ("00000111") ;  ---WORKING

--variable N: integer:=conv_integer  (size) ; -- Not working
type memory is array (N downto 0 ) of std_logic_vector (31 downto 0 ); 

variable RAM :memory;
```

Only reason to do this type of coding is send as much data as possible to FPGA .As I need to send Data from DDR to Custom IP via DMA in vivado may be more than 100 MB. so kindly guide me if I am trying to implement in wrong way as stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in VHDL. What kind of hardware would be generated by your code? If you don't know, the synthesizer won't either.

The way to do this kind of thing is to set `N` to the largest value you want to support, and use `size` in your logic to control your logic appropriately. It's difficult to give more pointers without more information, but as an example, you could use a counter to address your ram, and have it reset when it's greater than `size`.

### Update

Here's a counter example. You have to make sure that `size` doesn't change while operating or it will fall into an unknown state. A real design should have reset states to ensure correct behaviour.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity example is
port (
    clk : std_logic;
    rst : in std_logic;
    size : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
    wr : in std_logic;
    din : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);
end entity;

architecture rtl of example is
    signal counter : unsigned(7 downto 0);

    type ram_t is array(0 to 255) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal ram : ram_t;
begin

    RAM_WR: process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if rst = '1' then
                counter <= (others => '0');
            else
                if wr = '1' then
                    ram(to_integer(counter)) <= din;

                    if counter = size then
                        counter <= (others => '0');
                    else
                        counter <= counter + 1;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process RAM_WR;

end architecture rtl;
```

Comment: Yes. I already thought about making a counter for that issue, but can you please give an example to use counter for addressing ram .

Comment: I have written that as follows. it gives me that error :  Formal <arg> has no actual or default value.Type integer is not an array type and cannot be indexed.

                  if (S_AXIS_TVALID = '1') then
 
    RAm (to_integer (Counter) ) <= S_AXIS_TDATA; 
     if (Counter = Size ) then 
        Counter <= (others => '0') ;
        else Counter <= Counter +1 ; 
     end if ;

Comment: I added the entity declaration and fixed a minor error. It compiles as is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only have a generic an array constraint in a process. Otherwise, the compiler cannot elaborate.

In a function or procedure, you can have truly variable array bounds.